# Cannot run vim in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, vim, ruby, shared-library

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 running vim produces output:

> vim: error while loading shared libraries: libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This happens as root and user. Have tried uninstalling and reinstalling

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge vim -y; apt-get autoremove --purge -y`
2. `sudo apt-get clean`
3. `sudo apt-get install vim`

Have tried uninstalling-re-installing from PPA

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install vim`
4. `sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/vim`
5. *repeat 1-3*.

Exact same result. Have installed the libruby package `libruby_2.3.0+1_all.deb` for xenial (16.04LTS) (libs): Libraries necessary to run Ruby [universe]

I have two Ruby versions installed -

```
ruby-1.9.1-p431 [ x86_64 ]  
ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
```

as well as system ruby

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Doesn't matter which ruby is default. Still same result. Obviously vim cannot be uninstalled either. Would appreciate any ideas.
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried temporarily uninstalling or reinstalling ruby?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the long and complicated update process is to blame.  See [this sticky Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946145).  If that were the case, then the fix would be to back up your $HOME folder, wipe the hard drive clean, install a fresh copy of Ubuntu, restore your $HOME folder, and install missing packages.  Good luck.